# Table with 17 columns for IEEE

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to make a table with 17 cols but it is going out of bounds. Can anyone help me?. There are four different sections with 4 cols each.

Current Table:

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{table*}[]
    \centering
        \caption{Simulation Parameters}
    \label{table_simulation_parameters}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|c||c||c||c||c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Gaussian} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Laplacian} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Binary} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Uniform} \\ \hline
    Algorithm & $\mu$ & $a$ & $\sigma$ & $\lambda$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ \\ \hline
    LMS & $0$ & - & - & $0.0$ & - & - & $0.4$ & - & - & $0.$ & - & - \\ \hline
    AVLMS & $0.003$ & $2$ & $0.005$ & $0.00005$ & $4$ & $0.00003$ & $0.015$ & $1$ & $0.0001$ & $0.00003$ & $4$ & $0.00002$ \\ \hline
    AV-GMCC & $0.02$ & $0.01$ & $0.095$ & $0.04$ & $0.4$ & $0.07$ & $0.2$ & $0.01$ & $0.01$ & $0.13$ & $0.8$ & $0.01$ \\ \hline
    AV-lncosh & $0.0001$ & - & -  & $0.00008$ & - & -  & $0.0001$ & - & -  & $0.0001$ & - & -  \\ \hline
    GCLD & $0.001$ & $2$ & $0.04$ & $0.000025$ & $4$ & $0.0006$ & $0.001$ & $1$ & $0.02$ & $0.0001$ & $4$ & $0.002$ \\ \hline
    KRSL & $0.015$ & $2$ & $0.37$ & $0.006$ & $0.4$ & $0.8$ & $0.016$ & $1.3$ & $0.5$ & $0.01$ & $0.8$ & $0.6$ \\ \hline
    PZA-LMS & $0.015$ & $2$ & $0.37$ & $0.006$ & $0.4$ & $0.8$ & $0.016$ & $1.3$ & $0.5$ & $0.01$ & $0.8$ & $0.6$ \\ \hline
    % & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Case II-a} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Case II-b} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Case II-c} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Case II-d} \\ \hline
    % Algorithm & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\lambda$ \\ \hline
    % LMS & $0.003$ & - & - & $0.0032$ & - & - & $0.0038$ & - & - & $0.0038$ & - & - \\ \hline
    % GMCC & $0.002$ & $2$ & $0.0001$ & $0.003$ & $2$ & $0.00005$ & $0.009$ & $1$ & $0.0001$ & $0.01$ & $1$ & $0.0001$ \\ \hline
    % GHSAF & $0.05$ & $0.01$ & $0.03$ & $0.04$ & $0.8$ & $0.07$ & $0.075$ & $0.01$ & $0.01$ & $0.08$ & $0.5$ & $0.01$ \\ \hline
    % NKP-LMS & $0.00015$ & - & -  & $0.00015$ & - & -  & $0.00007$ & - & -  & $0.00007$ & - & -  \\ \hline
    % NKP-GMCC & $0.008$ & $2$ & $0.047$ & $0.0001$ & $2$ & $0.0001$ & $0.005$ & $1$ & $0.19$ & $0.0035$ & $1$ & $0.15$ \\ \hline
    % NKP-GHSAF & $0.008$ & $0.2$ & $0.9$ & $0.01$ & $0.8$ & $0.4$ & $0.004$ & $0.05$ & $3.5$ & $0.01$ & $0.5$ & $0.6$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: If landscape, sidewaystable or adjusbox don't fit, I wuild divide it into two table* environments.

Comment: If you were designing this with pen and paper, how would you make it fit?

Comment: For big tables, you can maybe prepare a "supplementary material" deposit (as a readable text file) on Zenodo, for instance and link the corresponding DOI in your paper. Gigantic tables in pdf documents are not really useful.